# Angular 2 HTTPs POST ERROR In IE 11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I am using angular 2 to make post call.

```
create() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = JSON.stringify({message:'[START]});
    this.http.post('https://localhost:8888/client/get', body, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => console.log(data) ,
            err => console.log(err)         
        );
}
```

It works fine when I use `http://localhost:8888/client/get`, but when I'm trying to make a post call using `https://localhost:8888/client/get` I get the following error:

[image]

The rest web service is built on the spring boot. I access localhost via https protocol by using a self-signed certificate. I followed the steps as provided in [this](https://www.drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/) article to make access localhost through https.

Please advise how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the same piece of code with the different URL which has a proper certificate it is working. Hence it is clear that the issue is with the certificate. as a work around I used the suggestion provided in this
http://jonnyreeves.co.uk/2013/making-xhr-request-to-https-domains-with-winjs/.

Below is the work around in angular;

```
  ngOnInit() {
        this.get();
     }

get(){
     let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
     this.http.get('https://localhost:8888',options);
}
create() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = JSON.stringify({message:'[START]});
    this.http.post('https://localhost:8888/client/get', body, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => console.log(data) ,
            err => console.log(err)         
        );
}
```

After calling the get method we can use the post method.